# Binding preloaded image to div background-image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, html, background-image

I have preloaded 2 images using below statements:

```
    window.imgOK = $('<img src="' + '@Url.Content("~/images/OK.gif")' + '">');
    window.imgNOK = $('<img src="' + '@Url.Content("~/images/NOK.gif")' + '">');
```

Also, I have a div and in a certain moment and depending on some conditions I want to bind one of the above image to the div background-image, I mean, I want to set the div background-image with one of the above images.

For example, if some condition in my code is not satisfied, then I would like to do something like below in order to update div background-image as:

```
$('#MyDiv').css("background-image", window.imgNOK);
```

and if condition is satisfied:

```
$('#MyDiv').css("background-image", window.imgOK);
```

but it is not working so how to do this?

Comment: Console.log your window.imgOK and you will probably see what is spiting. If this in fact is your code, then it should be spiting and img html tag with src attr and you are trying to set that img tag to a css attribute...no way. You need to set only the src not the whole img tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it as a URL for it to be a background, based on the SOURCE of the image, not the image tag itself.:

```
$('#MyDiv').css("background-image", "url(" + window.imgOK.attr('src') + ")"  );
```